# Можете объяснить почему не работает вывод массивов? Принцип

Tags: javascript

Почему данный двумерный массив выводит св-ва и значения в консоль, а вот массив с именованными массивами не выводит?

```js
let peoples = [
    {name: 'Ivan', sour_name: 'Ivanov', age: 22},
    {name: 'Nikita', sour_name: 'Kurchenko', age: 20},
    {name: 'Alena', sour_name: 'Evseeva', age: 21},
    {name: 'Oleg', sour_name: 'Nikolaev', age: 23},
]
let newPeoples = peoples.map(man => {console.log(man.name + man.age)}) // Это понятно выводится.

// а Вот ниже вообще не выводится, типа someMans не функция. Но она же и не должна ею быть.
let Victor = {
    name: "Victor",
    age: 22,
    goroscop: "bliznetsy"
};
let Irka = {
    name: "Irka",
    age: 27,
    goroscop: "bliznetsy"
};
let Olga = {
    name: "Olga",
    age: 15,
    goroscop: "Kozerog"
};
let Alexey = {
    name: "Alexey",
    age: 80,
    goroscop: "Rak"
};
let someMans = {Alexey, Olga, Irka, Victor};// присваиваю переменной someMans массив с этими именами-переменными
let newMans = someMans.map(man => {console.log(man.name + man.age)})
```

Comment: В someMans вообще ошибка должна быть, даже 2, выполните в консоли и увидите, и это объект получается, по нему map не пройтись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы загоняете данные в объект а не массив

```
  let someMans = [Alexey, Olga, Irka, Victor];
```

```js
let peoples = [
    {name: 'Ivan', sour_name: 'Ivanov', age: 22},
    {name: 'Nikita', sour_name: 'Kurchenko', age: 20},
    {name: 'Alena', sour_name: 'Evseeva', age: 21},
    {name: 'Oleg', sour_name: 'Nikolaev', age: 23},
]
let newPeoples = peoples.map(man => {console.log(man.name + man.age)}) // Это понятно выводится.

// а Вот ниже вообще не выводится, типа someMans не функция. Но она же и не должна ею быть.
let Victor = {
    name: "Victor",
    age: 22,
    goroscop: "bliznetsy"
};
let Irka = {
    name: "Irka",
    age: 27,
    goroscop: "bliznetsy"
};
let Olga = {
    name: "Olga",
    age: 15,
    goroscop: "Kozerog"
};
let Alexey = {
    name: "Alexey",
    age: 80,
    goroscop: "Rak"
};
let someMans = [Alexey, Olga, Irka, Victor];// присваиваю переменной someMans массив с этими именами-переменными
let newMans = someMans.map(man => {console.log(man.name + man.age)})
```

Можно и так но нужно немного поработать напильником

```js
let peoples = [
        {name: 'Ivan', sour_name: 'Ivanov', age: 22},
        {name: 'Nikita', sour_name: 'Kurchenko', age: 20},
        {name: 'Alena', sour_name: 'Evseeva', age: 21},
        {name: 'Oleg', sour_name: 'Nikolaev', age: 23},
    ]
    let newPeoples = peoples.map(man => {console.log(man.name + man.age)}) // Это понятно выводится.

    // а Вот ниже вообще не выводится, типа someMans не функция. Но она же и не должна ею быть.
    let Victor = {
        name: "Victor",
        age: 22,
        goroscop: "bliznetsy"
    };
    let Irka = {
        name: "Irka",
        age: 27,
        goroscop: "bliznetsy"
    };
    let Olga = {
        name: "Olga",
        age: 15,
        goroscop: "Kozerog"
    };
    let Alexey = {
        name: "Alexey",
        age: 80,
        goroscop: "Rak"
    };
    let someMans = new Array(Alexey, Olga, Irka, Victor);// присваиваю переменной someMans массив с этими именами-переменными
    let newMans = someMans.map(man => {console.log(man.name + man.age)})
```

Comment: ааа, спасибо большое! Надо было в квадрат их ставить. Елки.

Comment: а да сорян, я сразу нажал, там просто была надпись: "вы можете проголосовать ток через 8 минут", чуть не забыл.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!